# font size is looking bigger than the given size in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have given 14 pt font size in photoshop cs6 but its looking bigger than that.whats going on?[image]

Comment: What's the resolution of the file (PPI)? Low resolution will cause font sizes to appear to be larger.

Comment: resolution is 300.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using points as a unit which, in short, is a typographic measure relative to the image resolution, at least in bitmap documents. The image resolution defines how many pixels are being represented by your 14pt:

- in 72 ppi: 14pt = 14px
- in 300 ppi: 14pt = ~58px

If you want to have consistent font sizes in Photoshop no matter at what image resolution you're working in, switch to pixel units for `Type` in `Preferences > Units & Rulers`